# jQuery.each return indexed array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
function gatherFollowers() {
            var followers = [];
            jQuery('.follower').each(function(index, value) {
                var i = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('data-id'));
                followers.push(i);
            });
            return followers;
        }
```

That should grab all attributes but in result it returns this:

```
[100, 99, 88, 72, 63, 34, 31, 30, 29, each: function, eachSlice: function, all: function, any: function, collect: function…]
```

How could I make it return simple array like this:

```
[4,29,30,31,32,34,36,37,60,61,63,72,76,77,88,99,100]
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code that prints the result of this function

Comment: Can you also post the code showing what has the class "follower"

Comment: there is foreach with <div class="follower" data-id="{$id}"></div>

Comment: I don't believe that's the result you get from this code. Seems to me that you have `prototypejs` loaded in addition to jQuery, and you're improperly enumerating your resulting array using `for-in`, which includes the prototyped functions. If the functions were actually directly in the Array as you show, their result would be `NaN`.

Comment: Yes, I have Prototype.JS also included

Comment: @ShiftedReality: Yes, I know. The issue has nothing to do with the answers below. The issue is that you're using `for-in` to enumerate your resulting Array. Am I correct that you're using `for-in` on the result of the `gatherFollowers()` function?

Comment: It's simple console.log

Comment: @ShiftedReality: Which `console.log`? Different consoles display data differently. The particular console you're using may show inherited methods in its display. In any case, it doesn't matter. How a particular console behaves has no impact on your code. Are you having an actual code issue?

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to get what you need - and .get()

```
function gatherFollowers() {
    return jQuery('.follower').map(function(i,v){
        return $(v).data('id');
    }).get();
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xnZBc/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with fixing the issue shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
function gatherFollowers() {
    var followers = $.map($('.follower'), function(value) {
        return parseInt($(this).data('id'), 10);
    });

    // followers should be an array of numbers
}
```

I've changed your code to use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and also to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) to access the HTML 5 data- `id` attribute.

Comment: This has nothing to do with fixing the issue shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact pushing this function result into object really helped me 
`followers.data = gatherFollowers();`

Now console.log shows

```
Object {data: Array[9], type: "custom"}
data: Array[9]
0: "100"
1: "99"
2: "88"
3: "72"
4: "63"
5: "34"
6: "31"
7: "30"
8: "29"
length: 9
__proto__: Array[0]
type: "custom"
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
//HTML
//<div id="1" class="follower">follower1</div>
//<div id="2" class="follower">follower2</div>

var followers = [];
$('.follower').each( function(index, value){
    var follower_id = $('.follower:eq(' + index + ')').attr('id');
    followers.push(follower_id)
});
console.log(followers)
//output [1,2]
```

Comment: There is no `.cell' in the questioner's HTML